# Join strings in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of lists. For example, I depicted it in the form of a dict_list dictionary and output it as a dataframe. I'm trying to write code that would combine rows with the same list items and add those that are not in it. In my example, this would be combining A [1,2,3],B[1,2],F[8] and G[8,3]  into a single row with the values [1,2,3,8]. Or combining C[4], D[5,6], E[5,4] into one line with the values [4,5,6]. Help with this task, I do not understand how to do it. For example :

```
dict_list={
    'name':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'],
    'number':[[1,2,3],[1,2],[4],[5,6],[5,4],[8],[8,3]]
}
pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
```

[image]

and what you need at the exit:

[image]

Comment: This is more a network problem. Also, 1) Why `name` for `[4,5,6]` is `B`? 2) your data is `list` type, not string as indicated in the question title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @QuangHoang states, and what I pointed out in your deleted question, here a way to find all [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

dict_list={
    'name':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'],
    'number':[[1,2,3],[1,2],[4],[5,6],[5,4],[8],[8,3]]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)

from itertools import tee
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


G = nx.Graph()
for _, s in df.explode('number').groupby('name'):
    if s.shape[0] > 1:
        [G.add_edge(*i) for i in pairwise(s['number'])]
    else:
        G.add_node(s['number'].iloc[0])
        
nx.draw_networkx(G)

[list(i) for i in nx.connected_components(G)]
```

Graph of network:

[image]

Output of connected notes:

```
[[8, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```